Getting [Error: Missing camera or camera roll permission] even when the permissions are allowed in ios
I am building an expo react-native application. This mobile is prebuilt hence have the IOS and the Android folders seperately. I added the permissions to the Info.plist file as described in https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/sdk-50/packages/expo-image-picker. And then the code for the launching the camera is below,
 async captureImageFromCamera(): Promise<ImagePicker.ImagePickerAsset[] | null> {
    const permissionStatus = await ImagePicker.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
    console.log(permissionStatus)

    if (permissionStatus.granted) {
      const response = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({ mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images });
      if (response.canceled) {
        throw new OperationCancelledError('Operation was cancelled by the user');
      }
      return response?.assets;
     }
    console.log(permissionStatus)
    throw new PermissionDeniedError('Camera Permissions are denied');
  }

But even when I allow the permissions in my ios device I am getting this error [Error: Missing camera or camera roll permission]
Even after I have accepted the camera permissions, I still get {"canAskAgain": false, "expires": "never", "granted": false, "status": "denied"} when i query the permission status using getCameraPermissionsAsync()
These are my dependency versions
"expo": "50.0.6",    
"react-native": "0.73.2",  
"expo-image-picker": "14.7.1",

Any suggestions how to solve this issue?

In XCode, info.plist file have you added Privacy string for Privacy - Camera Usage description

@Shivbaba'sson the strangest thing of all is that even when i have allowed the permissions when I query for the permission status, i am getting {"canAskAgain": false, "expires": "never", "granted": false, "status": "denied"}

Hi, have u added package expo-camera ?

@Shivbaba'sson Got it to work. i need to add the microphone usage permission which I have forgot to add. Phew :( Thanks for the support
